# Making too many request await Axios (ReactJS)

Tags: reactjs, axios

On the outside it seems not an issue, but when I open the DevTools and then go to network tab. It shows that there are 500 requests made. So how can I refactor the code so this will not happens?

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(
          "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/XiteTV/frontend-coding-exercise/main/data/dataset.json"
        );
        dispatch(getData(response.data));
        console.log('input');
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [dispatch]);
```

Comment: why do you have `dispatch` in useffect dependencies?

Comment: the issue is the `dispatch` in the `useEffect` dependency. Ideally it should be either empty to load ones `[]` or to load when there is a change in the variable.

Comment: I think @Kakiz saying correct but still rather than passing [dispatch]  just pass [] empty array for useEffect function so useEffect will get called only one time.

Comment: Is this `Redux` or `useDispatch`?

Comment: No matter if I remove dispatch in useEffect dependencies...there are still lot of request made.

Comment: @Kakiz redux in this case

Comment: most likely you have some conditional logic to render your component up in your tree that makes it mounts and unmounts indefinitely. your useEffect alone wouldn't trigger this infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

with redux first create a function which will push your request data into redux state like that outside your react component

```
export const getMyData = () => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    const response = await axios.get(
      "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/frontend-coding-exercise/main/data/dataset.json"
    );

    dispatch(getData(response.data));
  }
}
```

create a function that will extract data from redux. `state` is redux current state, `ownProps` is your component props, like `<Component customProp={1}/>`

```
const mapStateToProps = (state: any, ownProps: any) => {
  return {
     ...ownProps,
     myProps: state.user 
  };
};
```

In your connect Function pass the function which will store your data in redux state

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getMyData })(MyReactComponent);
```

that way you'll be able to access your data via your component props and also access your getMyData function and also the redux state you mapped to props

```
props.getMyData();
```

Comment: the code is hook based, your solution for classes.